# Building Hyperledger fabric using AWS templated - stack creation Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am trying to create hyperldger fabric stack using AWS blockchain template. I tried creating in Ohio region and virginia region. I am getting the same following error :

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [FabricEC2CommonStack]. . Rollback requested by user.

Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:0729:stack/FabricStack-FabricEC2CommonStack-1ESVQYI4LVJB/90bce4c0-3e5d2d5c was not successfully created: 
The following resource(s) failed to create: [EC2InstanceForDev].
```

my IAM role looks like following :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the one they have provided int he documentation.

Did anyone face the same problem ? What is the solution for the same ?

Thanks in advance !

Link for template - [Template Link](https://aws-blockchain-templates-us-east-2.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hyperledger/fabric/templates/simplenetwork/latest/hyperledger.template.yaml)

Stack creates nested stack for which I am not able to get the link but here is the template below :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  This template creates an EC2 instance to create artifacts required for the
  Fabric Network, as well as make it available for CLI access.
Parameters:
  ChannelName:
    Type: String
  RootDomain:
    Type: String
  Org1SubDomain:
    Type: String
  Org2SubDomain:
    Type: String
  Org3SubDomain:
    Type: String
  NetworkSubnetID:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
  EC2InstanceProfileArn:
    Type: String
  EC2KeyPairName:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
  EC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id'
  EC2InstanceType:
    Type: String
  NodeAMIOS:
    AllowedPattern: '^[0-9a-zA-Z-/]*$'
    ConstraintDescription: >-
      Can include numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, hyphens (-),
      and forward slash (/)."
    Default: Amazon-Linux-HVM
    Description: AMI type.
    Type: String
  DockerReleaseTag:
    Type: String
  DockerImageRepositoryURL:
    Type: String
  LogLevel:
    Type: String
  NestedTemplateOrigin:
    Type: String
Mappings:
  LinuxAMINameMap:
    Amazon-Linux-HVM:
      Code: AMZNLINUXHVM
  AWSAMIRegionMap:
    AMI:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: amzn-ami-hvm-2017.09.1.20180307-x86_64-gp2
    ap-northeast-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-a77c30c1
    ap-northeast-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-5e1ab730
    ap-south-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-7c87d913
    ap-southeast-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-e2adf99e
    ap-southeast-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-43874721
    ca-central-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-5b55d23f
    eu-central-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-ac442ac3
    eu-west-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-3bfab942
    eu-west-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-dff017b8
    sa-east-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-5339733f
    us-east-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-1853ac65
    us-east-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-25615740
    us-west-1:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-bf5540df
    us-west-2:
      AMZNLINUXHVM: ami-d874e0a0
  RegionToResourceRegion:
    us-east-1:
      to: us-east-1
    us-east-2:
      to: us-east-2
    us-west-2:
      to: us-west-2
    us-west-1:
      to: us-west-2
    ca-central-1:
      to: us-east-1
    eu-central-1:
      to: us-east-1
    eu-west-1:
      to: us-east-1
    eu-west-2:
      to: us-east-1
    eu-west-3:
      to: us-east-1
    ap-northeast-2:
      to: us-east-1
    ap-northeast-1:
      to: us-east-1
    ap-southeast-2:
      to: us-east-1
    ap-southeast-1:
      to: us-east-1
    sa-east-1:
      to: us-east-1
    ap-south-1:
      to: us-east-1
  RegionInformationMap:
    us-east-1:
      ResourceAccountId: 354658284331
    us-east-2:
      ResourceAccountId: 763976151875
    us-west-2:
      ResourceAccountId: 712425161857
Resources:
  EC2InstanceForDev:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT10M
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile: !Select 
        - 1
        - !Split 
          - /
          - !Ref EC2InstanceProfileArn
      ImageId:
        'Fn::FindInMap':
          - AWSAMIRegionMap
          - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
          - 'Fn::FindInMap':
              - LinuxAMINameMap
              - Ref: NodeAMIOS
              - Code
      InstanceType: !Ref EC2InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref EC2KeyPairName
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
          DeviceIndex: '0'
          GroupSet:
            - Ref: EC2SecurityGroup
          SubnetId: !Ref NetworkSubnetID
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value:
            'Fn::Join':
              - '-'
              - - Ref: 'AWS::StackName'
                - DevBox
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64':
          'Fn::Join':
            - ''
            - - |
                #!/bin/bash -x
              - |
                yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
              - |
                res=$?
              - |
                echo $res
              - |
                mkdir /tmp/fabric-install/ 
              - |
                cd /tmp/fabric-install/ 
              - 'wget '
              - !Join 
                - ''
                - - !Ref NestedTemplateOrigin
                  - HyperLedger-BasicNetwork.tgz
              - |2
                 -O /home/ec2-user/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork.tgz
              - |
                cd /home/ec2-user
              - |
                tar xzvf HyperLedger-BasicNetwork.tgz
              - |
                rm /home/ec2-user/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork.tgz
              - |
                chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user HyperLedger-BasicNetwork
              - >
                chmod +x
                /home/ec2-user/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork/artifacts/first-run-standalone.sh
              - >-
                /home/ec2-user/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork/artifacts/first-run-standalone.sh 
              - 'Fn::Join':
                  - ' '
                  - - 'Fn::FindInMap':
                        - RegionToResourceRegion
                        - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                        - to
                    - Ref: RootDomain
                    - Ref: Org1SubDomain
                    - Ref: Org2SubDomain
                    - Ref: Org3SubDomain
                    - Ref: ChannelName
                    - Ref: DockerImageRepositoryURL
                    - 'Fn::FindInMap':
                        - RegionInformationMap
                        - 'Fn::FindInMap':
                            - RegionToResourceRegion
                            - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                            - to
                        - ResourceAccountId
              - |+

              - |
                res=$?
              - |
                echo $res
              - |
                # Signal init result
              - '/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $res '
              - '         --stack '
              - Ref: 'AWS::StackName'
              - '         --resource EC2InstanceForDev'
              - '         --region '
              - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
              - |+

    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: a2197890-b7f7-42f2-bba2-940b28f0a0a9
Outputs:
  ExplorerURL:
    Value: !Join 
      - ''
      - - 'http://'
        - !GetAtt 
          - EC2InstanceForDev
          - PublicDnsName
        - ':8080'
  DevDesktopInstanceId:
    Value: !Ref EC2InstanceForDev
  DevDesktopInstancePrivateDnsName:
    Value: !GetAtt EC2InstanceForDev.PrivateDnsName
  DevDesktopInstancePublicDnsName:
    Value: !GetAtt EC2InstanceForDev.PublicDnsName
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
    a2197890-b7f7-42f2-bba2-940b28f0a0a9:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 60
        'y': 90
      z: 1
      embeds: []
```

Comment: Can you link the template? Also are there more error details in the cloudformation event log? There should be a more specific root cause error.

Comment: Here is the link for template - 
"https://aws-blockchain-templates-us-east-2.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hyperledger/fabric/templates/simplenetwork/latest/hyperledger.template.yaml"
Also their is a nested stack gets created in that template you can see "EC2InstanceForDev"

Comment: Logs - 
2020-01-23 21:20:11 UTC-0800 EC2InstanceForDev DELETE_IN_PROGRESS -
2020-01-23 21:20:09 UTC-0800 example-FabricEC2CommonStack-95J2MKT50HM1 DELETE_IN_PROGRESS User Initiated
2020-01-23 21:19:55 UTC-0800 example-FabricEC2CommonStack-95J2MKT50HM1 CREATE_FAILED The following resource(s) failed to create: [EC2InstanceForDev]. 
2020-01-23 21:19:54 UTC-0800 EC2InstanceForDev CREATE_FAILED Received FAILURE signal with UniqueId i-09b91dcb4b9f87d4c
2020-01-23 21:16:36 UTC-0800 EC2InstanceForDev CREATE_IN_PROGRESS Resource creation Initiated
2020-01-23 21:16:35 UTC-0800 EC2InstanceForDev